# Something weird in for loop speed

Tags: objective-c

here is a part of my program code:

```
int test;
for(uint i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
    test++;
}
```

the whole program takes `0.5` seconds to finish, but when I change it to:

```
int test[1];
for(uint i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
    test[0]++;
}
```

it will takes `3.5` seconds! and when I change the `int` to `double`, it will gets very worse:

```
double test;
for(uint i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
    test++;
}
```

it will takes about `18` seconds to finish !!!

I have to increase an `int` array element and a `double` variable in my real `for` loop, and it will takes about `30` seconds!

What's happening here?! Why should it takes that much time for just an increment?!
I know a floating point data type like `double` has different structure from a fixed point data type like `int`, but is it the only cause for such a big different time? and what about the second example which is also an `int` array element?!

Thanks

Comment: 1700 iterations?  That's really abysmal performance for any of those scenarios.

Comment: Is this happening in some sort of larger loop? 1700 iterations doesn't seem like enough for you to be seeing any difference in performance.

Comment: as I mentioned in the beginning, it's a part of a bigger program, not the whole program! :)

Comment: yeah, it's inside some other loops..., but the only thing which is matter, is the data type that cause this difference...

Comment: Compilers are allowed to remove code which isn't used. I assume your tests aren't fair because of some code you're not showing.

Comment: And the initial values for test ??

Comment: Any discussion is probably going to be meaningless without seeing the outer loop.  Allocating a double is not free, after all.

Comment: In the second exmaple (3.5 sec), what is the perf. when you do not increment the test[0] value ?

Comment: Either there's a LOT more going on than the code you have shown, or you are running inside a JVM on a TRS-80.

Comment: This makes entirely no sense and wont be of any help to anyone else unless you give us more information - hence vote to close.

Comment: it's ObjectiveC with Xcode. let's consider the compiler will remove the "test++" because of being useless, so why should it takes 18 seconds more, just because of an increment on a 'double' variable?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your question yourself.

float (double) operations are different from integer ones. Even if you just add `1.0f`.

Your second example takes longer than the first one just because you added some pointer refernces. An array in C is -bottom down- not much different from a pointer to the first element. Accessing any element, even the first one, would cause the machine code to load the starting address of the array multiply the index (0 in this case) with the length of each member (4 or whatever bytes int has) and add that (0) to the pointer. Then it has to dereference the pointer, meaning to acutally load the value at that very address. Add one and write back the result.

A smart modern compiler should optimize this a bit. When you want to avoid this optimization, then modify the code a bit and don`t use a constant for the index.

I never tried that with a modern objective-c compiler. But I guess that this code would take much loger than 3.5s to run:

```
int test[2];
int index = 0;
for(uint i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
    test[index]++;
}
```

If that does not make much of a change then try this:

```
-(void)foo:(int)index {
  int test[2];
  for(uint i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
      test[index]++;
  }
}
```

and then call `foo:0;`

Give it a try and let us know :)

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. Your second example, makes it lower to 2.2s :) so thanks for that important point :)

Comment: I thought it's maybe because of a little slowness of ObjectiveC, so is it so even in pure C ?

Comment: Frankly I thought my example would be even slower. :) Well, I do not see anything that would be faster in C++. ObjC is slow when it comes to calling methods (lots of times in loops etc.). But it is not slow in general. In the end it is all just C.